# Timeout to read from Alluxio

Tags: presto, alluxio

I encountered this error while performing a Presto query on Alluxio. What does this timeout mean, and how can I fix it?

> com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error opening Hive split alluxio://xxxxx:19998/s3/data/m-00020 (offset=134217728,
>   length=67108864) using org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat:
>   Timeout to read 39963328512 from [id: 0x23615709, L:/xxxxx:34740 -
>   R:xxxxx/xxxxx:29999]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive this error when the Alluxio worker takes too long (configurable through `alluxio.user.network.netty.timeout`) to provide data to the client.

One simple workaround is to increase timeout.

However, this is generally a symptom of the worker being overloaded in some way. Common things to check in your setup:

1. Alluxio worker load, possibly a problem if your compute is co-located and there is no resource management
2. Alluxio worker to under file system load/bandwidth, this is often a bottleneck for remote storages like object stores.

If these are bottlenecks, you can try reducing the concurrency or increasing the number of nodes in your cluster.